# Windows Phone 8.1 print result of an HTTP request

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I can not print or process the data that I receive after making an HTTP request.
This is the code I wrote:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        String jsonUri = "hxxp://xxxxx/zzzz/yyyyyy; //censured

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(jsonUri);

        request.BeginGetResponse(GetDataCallback, request);

    }

    void GetDataCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
        if (request != null)
        {
            WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
            testo.Text = response.GetResponseStream().ToString();
        }
    }
```

I tried various solutions but I just can not print the result. 
apache I see the call, and the data from the app I could see that coming

Comment: Why are you still using `HttpWebRequest`, please use [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781239.aspx). [HttpClient MSDN sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HttpClient-sample-55700664)

Comment: please post how you solved it so it can be marked as answered